# Upload de imagem no Laravel não funciona no servidor web

Tags: php, laravel

Ao tentar realizar o upload de uma imagem no Laravel em um servidor web ele não está gerando a imagem. Ao usar o $request->hasFile('imagem') mesmo que a imagem esteja sendo enviada mas se eu rodar o mesmo projeto no servidor local ele funciona normalmente

**Esse é o retorno do request no servidor web (000webhostapp.com)**
[image]

**Esse é o retorno do request no servidor local(Xampp)**
[image]

No servidor web ele não sobe a imagem independentemente da extensão da imagem ou do tamanho

Eu criei uma função onde eu faço o upload da imagem onde eu passo o meu request e o objeto onde eu quero inserir a imagem:

```
    protected function uploadImage($request, $post){
        if ($request->hasFile('imagem')) {
            $id = $post->id;
            $image = $request->imagem;

            if (!is_null($image)){
                $file = $image;
                $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $type = 'posts';

                $fileName = time() . random_int(100, 999) .'.' . $extension; 
                $destinationPath = public_path('image/'.$type.'/'.$id.'/');
                $url = '/image/'.$type.'/'.$id.'/'.$fileName;
                $fullPath = $destinationPath.$fileName;

                if (!file_exists($destinationPath)) {
                    File::makeDirectory($destinationPath, 0775);
                }

                $image = Image::make($file);

                $image->save($fullPath, 100);
                return $url;
            }else{
                return $post->post_midia_url;
            }
        }
    }
```

Alterei a configuração do arquivo filesystems.php adicionando a configuração do ftp e também adicionei isso no .env